# Forge 3-Legged Oauth - Sign in as another User / Force logout

Tags: autodesk-forge

I got 3 legged to work, and I have my own session login/logout management.

After logout, if user wants to login again, and I send him to 
`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authorize`, it's going straight to my callback with the previous user already authenticated instead of prompting for new login.

Seems like Autodesk is storing the session as a cookie so the only way to switch users after authorizing is to clear out the browser cache/data

Is there a way to force logout, or something similar to "Sign in as another user"?

This is my first time doing oauth, so I am not sure I am missing something, but seems like there should be way to force clear out the session and force a new login.

---

## Edit

Let me further clarify what I am trying to achieve:

Here is what I have.
1. I direct the user to the authentication page directing it to:
`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=obQDn8P0GanGFQha4ngKKVWcxwyvFAGE&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F{{mycallback}}%2Fcallback%3Ffoo%3Dbar&scope=data:read`

2. The user logins in with his Autodesk credentials
3. The authorization flow redirect's the user to `mycallback.com/callback/?code={{code}}
4. My backend get's the `code` parameter from the url request, and makes a `POST` request to `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/gettoken`
5. The request returns, among other things, an `access_token`
6. I store the `access_token` to the user's session, and use that to make the next requests to the API.

Up to this point, it works as I expect. Now I want to log the user out, and potentially sign in as a different user.

7. A /logout end point on my server clears the user session, eliminating the stored access_token.
8. Once the back end realized there is not active session/access_token, it redirect the user to the authentication flow (step #1 above).
9. At this point, I would expect to see another Autodesk login page, but instead, Autodesk's server automatically authorizes without a new login, and redirects user to call back, and the user logs in again.

So to rephrase my question, how do change the behavior on #9 above, so that the user has to re-enter his credential?

I am running into this often during development, where I login with my personal account, then I logout, and I would like to login with my work account.
Currently, the only way i can do that, is by Clearing my browser's cache. 
That leads me to think Autodesk is storing the session in the browser, and that's why it's re-authenticating without getting new credentials.

The same behaviour happens on your dm.autodesk.io
After the first login, if i try to authorize again, I am not prompted for an login the 2nd time, instead it automatically re-logins in the first user I logged in with.

If I understand what's happening correctly, seems that the API should have an end-point that we can call when I user logs out to force a re-authentication.

Makes sense?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just load this URL: "https://accounts.autodesk.com/Authentication/LogOut"
This will log out previous user session and a new user can logged in.

Refer this for more details: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/log-out-forge

Comment: Thanks for recording the solution. Unfortunately this is didn't exist when the question was asked 2+ years ago. Marked and answered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by *"I send him to https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authorize"* but this has to happen on your server.

Check my sample at https://dm.autodesk.io: Allow popups and click the "User Data" in the navbar. Once you logged in, the user session is stored securely on the server. If you reload the page it will log you in automatically. If you click the navbar button again it will clear the session on the server and if you reload you will not be logged in. I guess that's the behaviour you are looking for.

The code for this project is located [there](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-boilers.nodejs/tree/master/6%20-%20viewer%2Bserver%2Bdata-mng%2Bderivatives). The 3-legged logic is handled from [there](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-boilers.nodejs/blob/master/6%20-%20viewer%2Bserver%2Bdata-mng%2Bderivatives/src/server/api/endpoints/forge.js) and look as below (node.js):

```
import ServiceManager from '../services/SvcManager'
import { serverConfig as config } from 'c0nfig'
import { OAuth2 } from 'oauth'
import express from 'express'

module.exports = function() {

  var router = express.Router()

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // 2-legged client token: exposes a 'data:read' only token to client App
  //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  router.get('/token/2legged', async(req, res) => {

    try {

      var forgeSvc = ServiceManager.getService('ForgeSvc')

      var token = await forgeSvc.request2LeggedToken('data:read')

      res.json(token)

    } catch (error) {

      res.status(error.statusCode || 404)
      res.json(error)
    }
  })

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Initialize OAuth library
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  var oauth2 = new OAuth2(
    config.forge.oauth.clientId,
    config.forge.oauth.clientSecret,
    config.forge.oauth.baseUri,
    config.forge.oauth.authorizationUri,
    config.forge.oauth.accessTokenUri,
    null)

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // login endpoint
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  router.post('/login', function (req, res) {

    var authURL = oauth2.getAuthorizeUrl({
      redirect_uri: config.forge.oauth.redirectUri,
      scope: config.forge.oauth.scope.join(' ')
    })

    res.json(authURL + '&response_type=code')
  })

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // logout endpoint
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  router.post('/logout', (req, res) => {

    var forgeSvc = ServiceManager.getService(
      'ForgeSvc')

    forgeSvc.delete3LeggedToken(req.session)

    res.json('success')
  })

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Reply looks as follow:
  //
  //  access_token: "fk7dd21P4FAhJWl6MptumGkXIuei",
  //  refresh_token: "TSJpg3xSXxUEAtevo3lIPEmjQUxXbcqNT9AZHRKYM3",
  //  results: {
  //    token_type: "Bearer",
  //    expires_in: 86399,
  //    access_token: "fk7dd21P4FAhJWl6MptumGkXIuei"
  //  }
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  router.get('/callback/oauth', (req, res) => {

    var socketSvc = ServiceManager.getService(
      'SocketSvc')

    // filter out errors (access_denied, ...)
    if (req.query && req.query.error) {

      if (req.session.socketId) {

        socketSvc.broadcast(
          'callback', req.query.error,
          req.session.socketId)
      }

      res.json(req.query.error)
      return
    }

    if(!req.query || !req.query.code) {

      res.status(401)
      res.json('invalid request')
      return
    }

    oauth2.getOAuthAccessToken(
      req.query.code, {
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        redirect_uri: config.forge.oauth.redirectUri
      },
      function (err, access_token, refresh_token, results) {

        try {

          var forgeSvc = ServiceManager.getService(
            'ForgeSvc')

          var token = {
            scope: config.forge.oauth.scope,
            expires_in: results.expires_in,
            refresh_token: refresh_token,
            access_token: access_token
          }

          forgeSvc.set3LeggedTokenMaster(
            req.session, token)

          if(req.session.socketId) {

            socketSvc.broadcast(
              'callback',
              'success',
              req.session.socketId)
          }

          res.end('success')

        } catch (ex) {

          res.status(500)
          res.end(ex)
        }
      }
    )
  })

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // logout route
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  router.post('/logout', (req, res) => {

    var forgeSvc = ServiceManager.getService(
      'ForgeSvc')

    forgeSvc.logout(req.session)

    res.json('success')
  })

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // 3-legged client token: exposes a 'data:read' only token to client App
  //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  router.get('/token/3legged', async (req, res) => {

    var forgeSvc = ServiceManager.getService(
      'ForgeSvc')

    try {

      var token = await forgeSvc.get3LeggedTokenClient(
        req.session)

      res.json({
        expires_in: forgeSvc.getExpiry(token),
        access_token: token.access_token,
        scope: token.scope
      })

    } catch (error) {

      forgeSvc.logout(req.session)

      res.status(error.statusCode || 404)
      res.json(error)
    }
  })

  return router
}
```

Comment: Hi Phillippe - I added some more details to my question.

Comment: I see, yes I think that if you are logged in your A360 account on the same browser it will use the session data. I will check if there is a way around it. One workaround is to also log out from A360